I am a New-zealand citizen living in USA for 20 years moved here when I was 55 can I apply for a pension ..when can apply once back in New-zealand
we moved to the United States when we were 55 stayed 20 years  my husband is still working as we are only entitled to a small pension we want to move back home can we apply for our New-zealand pension when we move back as it is greater than the USA pension

The NZ Super eligibility criteria are described here.
One of the requirements is that you must have lived in New Zealand for a certain number of years from age 20. This must include 5 years from age 50.
The total number of years you need is based on your date of birth.
These years (including the 5 years from age 50) do not need to be consecutive.
There is a step-by-step guide to help you understand the criteria and see whether you may meet it.
